# configuring tsconfig.json and intellisense false error messages

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, intellisense

Visual studio 2017, typescript. As soon as I add "**/*.spec.ts" to exclude settings in tsconfig.json the IDE's intellisence starts to complain with multiple "cannot find module" errors. Those errors are false and doesn't influence tasks, neither build not test. but they do affect my attention as real errors get masked. What can I do with it?

with this configuration errors show up as soon as I open any .spec.ts file

"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],

whit this configuration no errors present.

"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],

but build goes OK with both of them